# Open question on autonomous navigation/mapping

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to solve a  problem where i want my robot to go around our office space without hitting anything and create a map of our office which i can use it in future. One way of create a map is to teleoperate the robot and create a map, which is straight forward. But this process becomes very tedious if your office is very large. I am trying to automate the process.

The main difficulty i am facing is i don't want my robot to go into any cubical's while mapping, i just want it to stay it in the aisles.  If i use LaserScan data and write a simple algorithm for obstacle avoidance, the robot goes into the cubical's and hit gets stuck or hits small objects or disturbs the people who are working, i don't want that to happen.

I thought i can use point cloud data to make my robot stay in the aisles and not go into cubical's. At  present, i am able to get pointclouds from kinect and use plane model segmentation algorithm to find planes.

But i have no idea what to do next or how to use these planes to make the robot move/navigate so that they just stay in aisles.

Any ideas how i can proceed the problem?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236711/open-question-on-autonomous-navigation/mapping./) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-06-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can get started with [ROS navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation).

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0